# how do i convert SQL query to laravel Eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

What i want to do is convert this query , i want to use pagination but when i use query like this pagination not working

```
 DB::select('SELECT *, ( ( weight * 400 ) + Making_charge) AS Sum FROM products WHERE '.$cat.' ='. $id.' ORDER BY sum ASC');
```

when i try to use pagination i get this error

```
Call to a member function links() on array (View:
```

i tried type casting but that did not work either

can anyone provide me valid reason or solution without disliking it
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `Call to a member function links() on array` is because the QueryBuilder returns an array. Not a collection as Eloquent.

I changed your SQL query to use double quotes in order to use string interpolation, and the work `sum` to `product_sum`, since `sum` is a reserved word by mysql.

```php
"SELECT *, (( weight * 400 ) + making_charge) as product_sum FROM products WHERE {$cat} = {$id} ORDER BY product_sum ASC";
```

Your query, using eloquent, will look as somethin like this:

```php
Product::query()
    ->where($cat, $id)
    ->select(['*', DB::raw('(weight * 400 + making_charge) as product_sum')])
    ->orderBy('product_sum')
    ->get();
```

This query returns a collection. You can also paginate using laravel pagination:

```php
$items_per_page = 10;

Product::query()
    ->where($cat, $id)
    ->select(['*', DB::raw('(weight * 400 + making_charge) as product_sum')])
    ->orderBy('product_sum') // The default direction is ASC
    ->paginate($items_per_page);
```

Comment: you are awesome , thnk u